# Having multiple ResultSets in parallel on same connection.. Will it cause any problem? [Mysql/Postgres]

Tags: mysql, postgresql, connections, jdbc

I have tried out the following in my local machine using jdbc/mysql:

- step 1: conn = getNewConnection
- step 2: stmt1 = "new statement" using connection 'conn'
- step 3: stmt2 = "new statement" using the same connection 'conn'
- step 4: resultSet1 = execute stmt1
- step 5: resultSet2 = execute stmt2
- step 6: operating on both resultset 1 and 2
- step 7: proper closing of all resources

worked fine in my machine. Can I be sure of this behaviour always (Mysql/Postgres with JDBC )? Will there be any issue?

Comment: I'm unsure about JDBC & postgre, mais it's strange that "it works on my machine": PDO+PHP requires the 1st statement cursor to be closed first AFAIR, so you cannot fire the 2nd statement until then. I would do a check on your "production" first, since this questions highly depends on what your "production" environment is.

Comment: i have tried it with JDBC and MySql...(i need to know behaviour in production either with Mysql or Postgres) @Xenos

Comment: Why are you executing 2 different queries at the same time anyway? If you're combining the resultsets, that would be better done in the database. If you're not combining them, you can execute them one after the other.

Comment: Without knowing what the "production environment" is, I think none will be able to help.

Comment: As well as the above production env information, please tell us more about step 6 - what are you doing when you are operating on result sets?
Are these asynchronous operations?

Comment: @DavidButtrick On assuming that you mean multi-threading (by quoting 'asynchronous operations'), we don't do multi-threading on step 6 (only synchronous operations )

Comment: It may help to clarify what's happening in steps 2 through 5. In 2 and 3, are you preparing your statements? You say you're executing the statements in 4 and 5. Also - in 4 and 5, are you retrieving the entire result set in memory, and then working with the result sets? If there's no further interaction with the specific statements afterwards, then this may actually not be multiple result sets in parallel, as far as the DB is concerned.

Answer (score 1):

SQL is not made for parallelism.  Adding such in your code will only make things more complex, and *possibly* slower.

For now, focus on writing *non-parallel* code.  When finished, you may need to ask the question of "how can I make this faster", with the sub-question of "would parallelism help".  The former question may involve indexes, reformulation of the query, merging two queries into one, etc.  Parallelism (in the application) is only rarely the 'right' way to approach SQL work.